# Ошибка — повторный вход в функцию (php)

Tags: массивы, php

Доброго времени суток.
При переборе массива переменная «заворачивает» назад. Почему?

Код:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value) {
if ($key == "username") {$username = $value;}
elseif ($key == "phone") {$phone = $value;}
elseif ($key == "email") {$email = $value;}
elseif ($key == "shiptype") {$shiptype = $value;}
elseif ($key == "cardtype") {$cardtype = $value;}
elseif ($key == "description") {$description = $value;}
else {
    $id = $key;
    $volume = $value;
}

$zakaz .= 'Товар: '.$id.', количество — '.$volume.'<br />';
}
echo 'Имя: '.$username.'<br />Телефон: '.$phone.'<br />Почта: '.$email.'<br />Тип доставки: '.$shiptype.'<br />Метро: '.$cardtype.'<br />Примечание: '.$description.'<br />';
echo $zakaz;
```

В $_POST я получаю неизвестное количество $key=>$value, поэтому сначала отсеиваю известные значения $key, а оставшиеся нужно перечислить в конце. Но получается на выходе:

```
Имя: %user%
Телефон: %phone%
Почта: %mail%
Тип доставки: %mail%
Метро: %metro%
Примечание: %additional%
Товар: 1, количество — 1000
Товар: 8, количество — 5
Товар: 9, количество — 4
Товар: 9, количество — 4
Товар: 9, количество — 4
Товар: 9, количество — 4
Товар: 9, количество — 4
Товар: 9, количество — 4
Товар: 9, количество — 4
```

Хотя пользователь выбрал товар №9 один раз, он перечисляется 7 раз. ЧЯДНТ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так вы в каждой итерации foreach прибавляете к $zakaz некую строку. Решение:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value) {
if ($key == "username") {$username = $value;}
elseif ($key == "phone") {$phone = $value;}
elseif ($key == "email") {$email = $value;}
elseif ($key == "shiptype") {$shiptype = $value;}
elseif ($key == "cardtype") {$cardtype = $value;}
elseif ($key == "description") {$description = $value;}
else {
  $id = $key;
  $volume = $value;
  $zakaz .= 'Товар: '.$id.', количество — '.$volume.'<br />';
}
}
```

Хотя у вас вообще подход неверный.

Мой совет: передавать покупки отдельно(`<input type="hidden" name="items[<?=$id?>]" value="<?=$quantity?>" />`) + примерно такое. Просмотрите результат, должно понравиться(если я не накосячил где).

```
$order = new stdClass;
$order->items = array();
foreach (array('username','phone','email','shiptype','cardtype','description') as $code)
  $order->$code = (string)@$_POST[$code];
foreach ($_POST['items'] as $id => $q)
  $order->items[$id] = $q;

var_dump($order);
```

Comment: Сейчас попробую ваш совет. P.S. покупки и прочую информацию я передаю ajax'ом через serializeArray().

Answer (score 0):

Для начала постарайтесь выявить причину, по которой товар №9 приходит Вам 7 раз. А из кода видно, что такое количество строк с товаром №9 Вам именно приходит в `$_POST`. Вот где, как говорится, собака порылась. А если Вы модифицируете **работающий** код для того, чтобы подстроить его под косяк, который возникает по невыясненным причинам, то это традиционно называется "костыль". Не надо так :) начните с главного - почему он Вам приходит 7 раз? а убирать товар в `items` или нет - тут совершенно не важно. Это влияет на красоту кода, а не на его работоспособность. Ваш код вполне рабочий, ищите почему 7 раз приходит.